# How to make links in nav different color than links in body?

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

I apologize if this has already been asked, but I wasn't able to find the answer on here or Google. I have a website I am building and I want the links in the navbar to be white, but I want the rest of the body to have blue links. This should be pretty simple, but for some reason my CSS is not working to achieve this. I will put my code below I use SCSS so the syntax is a little different, but I have checked and my CSS file is correct when I format it.

```
nav {
@include border-radius(5px);
background-color: $navbackground;
width: 99%;
position: fixed;
padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
text-align: center;
    a {
        color: $fontcolor;
        margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
        &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sanserif;
    background-image: url("../images/homebackground.png");
    a {
        @include text-shadow(#000);
        color: $linkcolor;
        text-decoration: none;
        &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried moving the color: $fontcolor; to nav instead of nav a, but that did not work either. I know I can use an inline style to achieve this, but I prefer to keep all my styles in a CSS file. Thanks in advance!

$fontcolor = white
$linkcolor = blue

Comment: Let's see your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your CSS you actually have the same [specificity level](https://specificity.keegan.st/), on both selectors

> nav a
> body a
> 0 0 0 2

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGZvRL

---

Therefore the last declared style has precedence, in this case the body style. The quick solution is just change the order of the declaration:

1. First general styles `body`
2. After specific styles `nav`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjkYoN

---

Or just increase the specificity of your nav selector.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXdAba

Comment: This worked once I put nav rules after the body rules. Thank you!

Comment: @LoganByers glad to help U mate. I've included some demos .

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
a{
    color: #357;
}

.navBar > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```